# Is it possible to substitute BERT with MobileBERT under the hood of LayoutLM?

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

LayoutLM builds itself on top of BERT as the baseline, but I want to substitute BERT for MobileBERT because BERT is too large. Unfortunately, the Huggingface Transformers library doesn't give you the option to change the baseline model for LayoutLM. How should I go about swapping BERT for MobileBERT? I'm aware they have very different configurations.

I'm aware this is a very broad question and a wide topic, but I can't find anything about it online. How would I go about it and where should I start?

Answer (score 0):

LayoutLM can be traind with the MiniLM models but with a slight accuaracy loss.

Comment: Would you have any references for this?